# ImageNet: what does top-five error means?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, computer-vision

One of the evaluation method for ImageNet Competition (classify 1,000 categories images) is top-5 error, what does that mean?

See: http://www.image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/

Answer (score 9):

Top-5 error, also known as rank-5 error is simply an instantiation of Rank-N error metric with $(N=5)$.

Rank $N$ error is the fraction of test samples $x_i$ where the correct label $y_i$ does not appear in the top $N$ predicted results of the model when results are sorted in decreasing order of confidence, or $P(y_i|x_i)$.

In [ILSVRC 2014](http://image-net.org/challenges/LSVRC/2014/index), the error metric for classification was:

\[
e = \tfrac{1}{n} \cdot \sum_k \min_{i} d(c_i, C_k)
\]

**where**

\[
  d(a, b) =
  \begin{cases}
   0       & \text{if } a = b \\
   1       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\]

$c_i$ is the predicted label and $C_k$ is the ground truth label. There are $n$ possible labels with $k=1, ..., n$.

Comment: Great! One clarification, what does c and capitalized C mean?

Comment: Here big C is one of the ground truth labels and little c is one of the predicted labels.

Comment: sabalaba -- could you add that information to your answer?

Answer (score 4):

the top-5 error rate (of a model) is the fraction of test images for which the correct label is not among the five labels considered most probable by the model [[1](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf)]

Answer (score 1):

I think the conditional evaluation of $d(A_i, B_k)$ should read:
$d(Ai, Bk) = 0$, if $A_i$ occurs in the top N probable classifications for a
               given ground truth class Bk.
          = 1, if it does not.

Here k takes values 0 to N-1. Where N is the number of classes.
For each $B_k$, there are $A_i$ probable classifications, where i takes values 
[0,  N-1]